# How do I know where a task came from in gradle?

Tags: gradle, antlr4

I have a complicated gradle build system that I inherited.   It works pretty well, but includes multiple plugins (java, groovy, antlr, jacoco, jetty, etc.).  I could not figure out how to accomplish something, so I did a './gradlew tasks --all'.  It turns out that there was a 'generate' task that did it (it re-generated the antlr-based code).  Great, but it took a long time, and I had no idea.

Where did that generate task come from?   What gradle command can I use to figure out where that task came from?  There was a custom antlr tasks that has a 'dependsOn 'generate', so I would think that it is coming from the antlr plugin, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible the find all tasks for a given plugin as well as specify a plugin for a given task. Please view the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/) - there's no link between a task and a plugin.

You may try the following piece of code (it might be error prone):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

project.plugins.each { p ->
    println "Plugin: ${p.getClass().name} "
    p.getClass().declaredFields.findAll { 
        Modifier.isStatic(it.getModifiers()) && 
        it.name.endsWith('_TASK_NAME') &&
        it.type.simpleName.equals('String')
    }.each {
        println " -> ${it.get(p)}"
    }
    println '\n'
}
```

Comment: Is that what You're looking for?